# Kind of time (yyyymmddThhmmZ)

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, angular-moment

I'm trying to generate links to Google calendar and see this tool:

https://decomaan.github.io/google-calendar-link-generator/

And the links are generated as:

https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Appointment+with+VULKOVICH%2C+BILL&details=a+Description&location=a+Location&dates=20210105T103300Z%2F20210114T103300Z

and as you can see the dates are like:

20210105T103300Z

and I am trying to convert this to my own dates but I don't know which type is this and how to format. I have the dates both, in moment or in date, but don't know how to convert.

Comment: So what have you tried? Format is `YYYYMMDDTHHIISS00Z`

Comment: This is ISO 8601

Comment: I try convert to ISO8601 but try moment().toISOString() or new Date().toISOString() return '2021-01-11T12:28:18.435Z' what is not exactly '20210111T122800Z' what I expected and don't works :-(

Comment: Since you're using moment.js: `moment().utc().format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]')`, or without a library `new Date().toISOString().replace(/\W/g,'').replace(/\d{3}Z/,'Z')`. This is really a duplicate of [*How to format a JavaScript date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date).

Comment: Thanks a lot....@RobG this works for me!!!! If you answer me I mark your solution as ok... if you can't I will write by myselt to help for someone looking for the same!!! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using moment.js: `moment().utc().format('YYYYMMDDTHHmmss[Z]')`, or without a library `new Date().toISOString().replace(/\W/g,'').replace(/\d{3}Z/,'Z')`. This is really a duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date).

**Source:** [comment by RobG Jan 11 at 12:58](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65666329/kind-of-time-yyyymmddthhmmz#comment-116102738)

Answer (score 0):

That's [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

The first part is the date in year-month-date order, the second part is the time and the final letter indicates the timezone (here Z for 'Zulu')

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I try moment().toISOString() or new Date().toISOString(); both return '2021-01-11T12:28:18.435Z' what is not exactly '20210111T122800Z' what I expected and don't works :-(